# How to disable places on google map V3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to migrate my application to latest version of Google map API and found that Google appends it's own items by default from Google Places directory to the map. 
It does not look right together with my own records as it creates duplicate items on the map which can be placed in correctly.

Is there an option how to hide this local businesses or to control what is shown and what is not?

here is sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map_canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 16,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.422833333333,25.323166666667),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            myOptions);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see on map, there are few tiny icons, which you can click on and information would appear in bubble. I need to hide this icons or at least disable on click event for this items.

Comment: there is no magic, just default settings

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just a pointer - this seems possible with [custom styled maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html#style_array_example). If I'm not mistaken, the feature type you're looking for would be `poi.business`, whose `visiblity` you would turn `off`.

There's a [wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) to help you build the options array.

Comment: wizard is really nice :)

Comment: The wizard really leaves me hanging. I'm left with a published style and a  mapId which I don't know how to use.. Maybe Ive misunderstood the entire purpose of this thing.

Comment: I have the same issue @Adam, how do you apply the style from this wizard to your map?

Answer (score 28):

You can remove it by adding the following code:

```
var styles = [
   {
     featureType: "poi",
     stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
     ]   
    }
];

var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,{name: "Styled Map"});
```

Comment: You don't actually need to use the StyledMapType - you can add the styles object to a standard `mapOptions` object and apply them through that.

Comment: If you need more styles based on @Zhaph-BenDuguid comment I found the map styles wizard - https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/.  After you hit finish it provides the styles array with everything you customized.  Took 2 seconds to remove businesses and attractions from the map I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The [Hiding Map Features With Styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/hiding-features) samples page explains exactly how to implement this.

Add the `styles` property to the options object and list `featureTypes` which you want to hide.

```js
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
  center: { lat: -33.86, lng: 151.209 },
  zoom: 13,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  styles: [
    // Repeat this object for each feature.
    {
      featureType: "poi.business",
      stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
    },
  ],
});
```

There are more examples of [Customizing a Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples#customizing-a-map) and the Styling Wizard (see "more options") is also very useful as others have pointed out.