# How to remove places from Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

### My map picture

I am implementing google maps in a React app with typescript and I need to remove the places from this map:

[image]

### Map Component

I have been searching through the docs some prop to remove those places but I can not find it. Props passed to my map component:

```
<Map 
 streetViewControl={false}
 mapTypeId="roadmap"
 mapTypeControl={false} 
 center={newCenter} 
 zoom={zoom} 
 style={{ flexGrow: "1", height: "100%" }} ></Map>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable places on google map V3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337266/how-to-disable-places-on-google-map-v3)

Comment: It is hard to tell from your question.  But I _think_ you want to hide the POIs (Places Of Interest). Related question: [How to add Snazzy maps Javascript Style array in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420031/how-to-add-snazzy-maps-javascript-style-array-in-react), related question: [javascript google maps v3.14 - how to hide poi now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495356/javascript-google-maps-v3-14-how-to-hide-poi-now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mapId and style generated at https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/studio/styles and add it to your mapOptions

```js
new google.maps.Map(div, {mapId});
```

Here is a screenshot from the map styling studio.

[image]